# Will database replication increase the size of the replicated database?

Tags: sql-server, performance, replication

First thank you for your time. We have a SQL Server database that was assigned to be replicated. the original size of the database was 5 GB for the datafile, not the log file. Now after the replication the data file is 4 times bigger around 19 GB. Any pointers to see what could happened will be appreciated. I know sql as developer and some little management but nothing about replication. The performance of the database has been damaged very bad so I am trying to see what need to be done to improve it. I do apologize for my English as well.

Comment: The data file for the database being larger should have almost nothing to do with affecting your database's performance, especially for a tiny database of 20 GB. It is weird and I don't think normal to see it quadruple in size from replication, so unfortunately it'll also be hard to advise on what to do if that's truly the reason it grew. More so you should focus on the particular queries that are slow if you're trying to solve a performance issue, rather than a little database growth. If you post a question about a few specific queries with their **execution plans** we should be able to help.

Comment: Did you compare the internal space instaed of the datafile space? maybe it's only a matter of data file autogrowth configuration.

Comment: Is there any compression at the source tables that is not replicated to the destination?
(Clustered columnstore indexes or data compressionin)

Comment: JD, MBuschi, trank you, but I think i asked the wrong question. what I wanted to ask was the following: the database that increased size from 5 GB to 20 GB was the original database (the Publisher, ) can the replication do that? I am sorry.