# Will database replication increase the size of the replicated database?

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have a SQL Server database that was assigned to be replicated. the original size of the database was 5 GB for the datafile, not the log file. Now after the replication the data file is 4 times bigger around 19 GB. Any pointers to see what could happened will be appreciated. I know SQL as developer and some little management but nothing about replication. The performance of the database has been damaged very bad so I am trying to see what need to be done to improve it.

Comment: Thanks  I will move it there

Comment: Is this transactional replication?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will database replication increase the size of the replicated database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/286541/will-database-replication-increase-the-size-of-the-replicated-database)